how to style item with grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr)) in virtual scroll
https://codepen.io/pen?editors=0010
 how to make in virtual scroll list item to grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr)) maybe cause items has style absolute, i dont know, in general i need to implement virtual scroll in react project, and in virtual scroll items be with this style grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))
`
this is example how my data want be to look like
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Avatar, List, message } from 'antd';
import VirtualList from 'rc-virtual-list';
const fakeDataUrl =
  'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20&inc=name,gender,email,nat,picture&noinfo';
const ContainerHeight = 400;
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const appendData = () => {
    fetch(fakeDataUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((body) => {
        setData(data.concat(body.results));
        message.success(`${body.results.length} more items loaded!`);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    appendData();
  }, []);
  const onScroll = (e) => {
    // Refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight#problems_and_solutions
    if (Math.abs(e.currentTarget.scrollHeight - e.currentTarget.scrollTop - ContainerHeight) <= 1) {
      appendData();
    }
  };
  return (
    <List>
      <VirtualList
        data={data}
        height={ContainerHeight}
        itemHeight={47}
        itemKey="email"
        onScroll={onScroll}
      >
        {(item) => (
          <List.Item key={item.email}>
            <List.Item.Meta
              avatar={<Avatar src={item.picture.large} />}
              title={<a href="https://ant.design">{item.name.last}</a>}
              description={item.email}
            />
            <div>Content</div>
          </List.Item>
        )}
      </VirtualList>
    </List>
  );
};
export default App;


Add your code in the question, not only links.
